# Error when generating release build, Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, apk

In order to reduce application's size, we made the following changes in in android/app/build.gradle:

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false => true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false => true
```

but when trying to generate the signed apk, we are encoutenring this error:

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> java.io.IOException: Failed to create path-project/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app1.0.5(65)-release.apk'

we tried adding

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

to gradle.properties but it's not working.

We are having the following content in android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    firebaseMessagingVersion = "+"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
    playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.5"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
}
```

}

and the following content in android/app/build.gradle

```
 esplits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "tcard${variant.versionName}(${variant.versionCode})-${variant.name}.apk"
            }
        }
    }

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }

packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the parenthesis that you added in the output filename are confusing the compiler or the system you're running it on does not allow the parenthesis as a valid character for a path.

Therefore, I would first try to change the filename (maybe using dashes instead of parenthesis?) before anything else.